# Applying CSS to a textbox within a formview control

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, formview

I am trying to apply css styles to textboxes within a formview. What is the correct way to do this as the form is not applying the styles below is part of the code where i was trying to apply the code

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="pappid" DataSourceID="applicantsbypappid" GridLines="Both"> 
<ItemTemplate>
               <%-- pappid:--%>
            <asp:Label ID="pappidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pappid") %>' />
            <br />

             <asp:Label ID="lblapplicantname" runat="server" CssClass="labels" Text="Applicant's Name:">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtapplicantfname"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pappfname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtapplicantmname"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pappmname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtapplicantlname"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("papplname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

css code

```
#txtapplicantfname
{
    width: 70px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0954A5;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-color: inherit;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-color: inherit;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Is there any special requirement by doing so ? Can I tell you other way around ?

Comment: There is no special requirement to doing it any certain way. Basically if i could find a way to add this command Text='<%# Bind("pappfname") %>' to individual textboxes all my css issues would go away. I am using the formview in order to bind the objectdatasource is there another way i could write code to bind the objectdatasource to the whole form? Hope that makes sense thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to assign the css directly, as the server side control ID renders in complete hierarchy with concatenation. Like in your case, there will be a `Content Place Holder and a Textbox (ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtapplicantfname)`. If there will be any more panels; `Tab Panel(ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_TabPanelID_txtapplicantfname)`, etc involve hierarchy will be disturbed.

You can do it like...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtapplicantfname" CssClass="txtapplicantfname"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pappfname") %>'></asp:TextBox>


.txtapplicantfname
{
width: 70px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0954A5;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-color: inherit;
border-left-width: 0;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-color: inherit;
border-right-width: 0;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-color: inherit;
border-top-width: 0;
font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that will not work for me as I have applied a standard textbox class to all textboxes. What if i was to put a table within the form would it see my css styles then?

Comment: But you want to assign specific class to TxtApplicationFname, and it should work if you assign specific class. that is answer.

Comment: Thanks I am re designing the form to use all class I was just under the impression you only use classes for css when you are going to have multiple controls with the same styles. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You know that when you use ASP.NET server controls, they are converted to HTML tags. The TextBox control will be rendered in HTML as an "input" tag. In the process however, ASP.NET does not give the same ID to the HTML tag. It will not be "txtapplicantfname", it will be something like "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtapplicantfname".

CSS styles apply to the HTML tags, not the ASP.NET code. So in the CSS stylesheet, if you refer to a control ID, you need to refer to the ID of the rendered HTML code. Your style should be:

```
#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtapplicantfname
{
(...)
```

Just display your page in a navigator (or execute in debug mode) and check the source to get the real IDs for the HTML tags.

Comment: -1 sorry. very wrong approach. especially when ASP.NET has these `ClientIDMode` and all. `CssClass` is there for a reason

Comment: Sorry i tried to run the form in debug mode however i can not find where it shows the full path to the id of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Within asp.net form you can use

```
 #<%= txtapplicantfname.ClientID%>
 {
      (...)
 }
```